# Postgres Error when Deploying to Digital Ocean Droplet

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql, digital-ocean, capistrano3

I keep getting an error while trying to deploy my app to a Digital Ocean Droplet using Capistrano's `cap production deploy`. The error message I get says:

```
rake aborted!
Gem::LoadError: Specified 'postgresql' for database adapter, but the gem is not loaded.
Add `gem 'pg'` to your Gemfile
```

but my Gemfile does include `pg` in `production`:

```
...
group :production do 
  gem 'rails_12factor'
  gem 'pg'  
end
...
```

What can be causing this?

#### New Development:

I tried resetting the db adapter back to `sqlite3`, just to see whether the deployment would go through, and got the same error:

```
Gem::LoadError: Specified 'sqlite3' for database adapter, but the gem is not loaded. Add `gem 'sqlite3'` to your Gemfile
```

Comment: Has you run `bundle install` and committed the changes in `Gemfile` and `Gemfile.lock`?

Comment: I can only run it locally. I tried creating a Gemfile locally, and installing it. I also tried installing the `pg` gem by itself. The gem gets installed without a problem, but I still get the error message.

Comment: What about the second part of my question - committing the changes to Gemfile & Gemfile.lock? If the code being deployed doesn't have the updated Gemfile.lock, it is likely to throw this error.

Comment: @PrakashMurthy you mean running the bundle locally?

Comment: Yes. If you are using capistrano, these steps are to be done locally.

Comment: @PrakashMurthy Same error. I ran `bundle install`, and pushed everything to the repo.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turned out to be a known bug for Win users. In your `Gemfile.lock`, change

```
sqlite3 (1.3.10-x86-mingw32)
```

to

```
sqlite3 (1.3.10-x64-mingw32)
```

I did it directly in my repo because each time I made this change locally and ran bundle install, the `x64` flag kept getting switched back.

Answer (score 0):

There is something else that you should address in your Gemfile -- I recommend that you remove this line from your Gemfile:

```
gem 'rails_12factor'
```

rails_12factor is a Heroku-specific logging gem and it will wreak much havoc on your  Digital Ocean Rails server. I can attest.